# Kotlin 1.3.11 has broken null-safety?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun handle() : String {
    null?.let { return "Ololo"}
}

val result = handle()
result.trim() // kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.CharSequence
```

Any ideas why null-safe Kotlin function return null?

Comment: I don't think `let` will run if its reference is null.

Comment: null?.let { }. What?

Comment: @DawidJamroży in real use case I have variable instead hardcoded null

Comment: Seems like a Kotlin type-system bug. This seems like it shouldn't compile unless the return type is `String?`

Comment: @Brucelet it shouldn't compile at all. `let()` is only supposed to run if its reference isn't null, which means there's technically a missing `return` statement. It seems like the compiler currently just adds in a `return null` though.

Comment: Yes you're correct. I was reading it as if it was `return null?.let { ... }`

Comment: @NickolaySavchenko I edited your question, because it is not android related.

Comment: There is no `return` and yet it compiles. Nasty bug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug caused by introducing [contracts](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts) for the standard functions `let`, `run`, `apply`, `also` in Kotlin 1.3.

The fix is targeted to the version 1.3.20. See [KT-28061](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28061) for details.

Comment: Thanks for reply, nice.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the Kotlin compiler is adding in a `null` return in case `let` doesn't execute. This is probably a bug, since it shouldn't compile, and doesn't in previous versions of Kotlin.

If we just compile your example, we get this:

```
@NotNull
public final String handle() {
    return null;
}
```

I think that's just a compiler optimization, since `null?.let()` will never execute.

Using an actual variable yields:

```
@NotNull
public final String handle() {
    return someNullableVariable != null ? "Ololo" : null;
}
```

In other words, `let()` doesn't execute if its reference is `null`. However, since this function needs to return something, the compiler just tells it to return `null`, since there's nothing else it could return.

Since the function is marked `@NotNull`, Kotlin will perform a null-check on anything referencing the function:

```
fun someOtherMethod() {
    handle().trim()
}
```

Becomes

```
public final void someOtherMethod() {
    String handle = handle();

    if (handle != null) {
        StringsKt__StringsKt.trim(handle).toString();
        return;
    }

    throw new Exception("null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.CharSequence");
}
```

There are two ways to handle this. You could change the return type on `handle()` to `String?`:

```
fun handle(): String? {
    someNullableVariable?.let { return "Ololo" }
}
```

Or you could return something else in case the variable is null:

```
fun handle(): String {
    someNullableVariable?.let { return "Ololo" }
    return "someNullableVariable was null"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It looks like Kotlin compiler bug, because on more earlier versions shown code not compilable. And it is expected behaviour from null-safe language in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

It has to be a bug, because:

- a return statement (or better: expression) is missing, since the lambda passed to `let` won't be invoked
- a function with `String` as return type should never return `null`.

---

Interestingly, in Kotlin 1.2.x this does not even compile:

```
fun handle() : String {
    null?.let { return "Ololo"}
}
```

> Error:(6, 0) A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

In Kotlin 1.3.11 it does.

In any case:

`let` won't be invoked, because the safe-call operator `?` evaluates to `null` (in this case).

Comment: It compiles for me with Kotlin 1.3.11 on Android Studio 3.4.

Comment: @TheWanderer True I pasted it in the online kotlin playground and accidentely used version 1.2.71. thx

Comment: This is really weird/interesting; With return only inside the `let` block, it won't return anything if the block isn't executed. Since it never executes, that effectively never returns anything. `fun handle() : String { }` shouldn't compile in the first place, because there's a chance it doesn't return. That is, unless Kotlin now returns default values if none is specified, but that would be really strange. Seems like a bug

Comment: @Zoe check my answer. It adds a null return

Comment: @TheWanderer yes, but it shouldn't. There's no part of that code that would have a fallback return.

Comment: @Zoe it really is weird :D